# How to return a data from Dataverse and assign to a variable inside Set Function in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, dataverse, powerapps-selected-items

I want to get data from the Dataverse table and then assign it to a variable. Below is my Set function.

In this line of code, I am trying to fetch the 1 index of my Table and get its value, and at the same time, I want to assign it to a SubHeaderValue variable.

Note: the state is a choice of multiple answers.

```
Set(SubHeaderValue, Index('myTableName', 1).state);
```

But I am getting the following error:

**The formula has side effects.**

Comment: Could you update your question with a snip of the error. Also where are you doing the `Set( ... )`? Is it in an IF statement? Please update question with the context of the `Set( ... )`

Comment: @SamNseir I am using the Set Function in onVisible property of a screen the error is the same as I mentioned above.

Comment: See this thread... https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/This-formula-has-side-effects-and-cannot-be-evaluated/td-p/403583

Comment: Can you try using this once: `Set(gvSubHeaderValue, First('myTableName').state);`? Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, this one works, but I need to access a different index of the table.